# Dojo PJAX library

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, dojo, pjax

Just like [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) for jQuery users, is there support for the same in Dojo (for folks using Dojo 1.7.x)?

Comment: None that I know of. [HTMLDecor](http://github.com/shogun70/HTMLDecor) is a javascript page template engine that runs in the browser and provides zero-config pjax. It is 7K when minified and gzipped and runs in the background so you could use it for pjax and dojo for everything else.

Comment: its not around to my knowledge either; it would however not be too difficult to implement, using dojo with dojo.layout.ContentPane (for xhr + a.href's) and dojo.topic (for fire). The tricky part are the 'context' window.history states - but those fractions of code doesnt look like it is jquery dependant

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful or not (as its not truly a dojo implementation of PJAX), but you should be able to use PJAX-Standalone https://github.com/thybag/PJAX-Standalone along side dojo without any issue's (basically pjax without the JQuery dependencies).